# GWT - adding pseudo Anchor

Tags: gwt

Is there any way in GWT to get a pseudo anchor ??????

I just want to have TextCell or textColumn in a Celltable with underlined text onclick of which a dialog box opens. This is a simple requirement and i donno why i am still not able to figure out how to do this. If it was to be written in HTML this is hardly 2 seconds job.

And i do not want to use Hyperlink or Anchor which causes a page refresh which seems unnecessary for my requirement.

This looks more complex than learning Japanese to me.

Comment: Can it be a button like in http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellSampler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ClickableTextCell](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/ClickableTextCell.html) is probably what you are looking for. You can quickly override it's render method to give the cell content the appearance you require, if the standard appearance is not suitable.

When the cell is clicked, the value updater of the `Column` that hosts the cell will be called.